# How to tie reset button to clear specific or all fields in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, calculator

so, I'm trying to make some sort of wind chill calculator to practice python and flask. And I got the basic calculator working, nothing too fancy, but I just can't figure it out how to reset all the fields.

Like the reset button does reset the `id="v"` and `id="t"` fields but it does not work for the `id="result"` field, and I can't seem to find anything of help.

Thinking of adding and `elif` condition for the reset button...

So is there a way to tie the reset button to specific fields? Or how could I make it reset everything?

```
# .py file:
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def calc():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 't' in request.form and 'v' in request.form:
            t = int(request.form.get('t'))
            v = int(request.form.get('v'))
            calc = fnc.wind_chill(t, v)
            return render_template('app.html', title='Chill Calc', calc=calc)
        elif ????:
            return ????
    else:
        return render_template('app.html', title='Chill Calc')
```

```
# .html file:
<div class="container">
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <label>Speed:</label>
        <input class="pure-u" type="number" id="v" name="speed" placeholder="Input speed here">
        <label>Temperature:</label>
        <input class="pure-u" type="number" id="t" name="temp" placeholder="Input temp here">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="calculate_button"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset_button"/>
            <div class="alert">
                Chill is:
                <input class="pure-u" type="text" id="result" value="{{ calc }}" onclick="reset"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press Reset, it will be reset to the default value.
After submitting the form, let's take the value for "calc" is 30. Then your HTML will look like this,

```
<input id="v" name="speed" placeholder="Input speed here">

<input id="t" name="time" placeholder="Input temp here">

<input id="result" ***value="30"***/>
```

Now, if you change the 30 to some other value and then if you press reset, then it will reset to 30. But the above 2 inputs don't have any default value, so those will reset to empty.

I have a solution for this. You can pass the calc value through Javascript.

```
<form>
    .....
    Chill is:
    <input class="pure-u" type="text" id="result"/>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('result').value = "{{calc}}"
</script>
```

This won't add any default value. So you can use Reset Button.

Note:
Use the input name instead of ID.

```
# wrong.
if 't' in request.form and 'v' in request.form:
    t = int(request.form.get('t'))
    v = int(request.form.get('v'))

# use name instead of ID
if 'time' in request.form and 'speed' in request.form:
    t = int(request.form.get('time'))
    v = int(request.form.get('speed'))
```

EDIT:
If you want this in server-side, then change the HTML like this,

```
<form method="POST">
    Speed: <input type="number" id="v" name="v" placeholder="Input speed here"><br>
    Temparature: <input type="number" id="t" name="t" placeholder="Input temp here"><br>
    <button name='btn' value="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <button name='btn' value="reset">Reset</button><br>
    Chill: <input type="text" value="{{calc}}" id="result"/>
</form>
```

And python file should be like this,

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def calc():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['btn'] == 'calculate':
            t = int(request.form.get('t'))
            v = int(request.form.get('v'))
            calc = t*v
        else:
            calc = ''
        return render_template('wind.html', title='Chill Calc', calc=calc)
    return render_template('wind.html', title='Chill Calc')
```

But this will send an additional request to the backend server. Since we have all the option available in the frontend itself, I think this is not a good method to use backend for resetting the page.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think I could just add that JS into the code and it will work.... Was stuck trying to figure out how I could add something to handle this in python. Cheers mate!

Comment: So you want to do reset the fields by python?

Comment: Yeah, I was stuck at trying to do it in the .py file... it never crossed my mind I could do it like this, but if you have a solution that works via the python code it's most welcome. I'm curious to see how it could be done like that as well.